# extending float: left property beyond image size

Tags: html, css

How do you extend the float:left property in css beyond the image size? In html I have

```
<img src = "http://www.inspiredtaste.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Easy-Banana-Bread-Recipe-2-1200.jpg" width = 50px> some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text
```

in css I have

```
img{float:left;}
```

How would you extend the float:left property beyond the image? That is, How would you keep the "some text" in the jfiddle all aligned even after the image ends?

https://jsfiddle.net/jhee2rrj/

Comment: Wrap the text in a `div`, and apply the style `display: table-cell;` to it.

Answer (score 0):

just add a margin to the text.

```
<p style="margin-left: 50px"> some text some text...</p>
```

Comment: How would I do that relative to the image? the image is somewhere in the middle of the page

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set the image height to fit-content, it wont work.
better to set margin to the image as the text height suitable:

```css
img
{
float:left;
margin-bottom:150px;
}

div{
height:200px;/*You can set this height as required*/
}
```

```html
<div><img src = "http://www.inspiredtaste.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Easy-Banana-Bread-Recipe-2-1200.jpg" width = 50px> some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text </div>
```